# Select where to display values from MySQL DB in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to display the values from MySQL database using CodeIgniter. Here, I am using `SELECT` to query to compare the multiple values using the `WHERE` condition.

I want to display the checked rows values from one page to another. I am passing the the checked value via URL. In the second page, I am getting the value from the URL, and using the `explode()` function to split the value and display using a `for` loop. Here, values are displaying correctly. But, when passing the array values to the `SELECT` query, it displays only the last rows.

I want to display all checked rows from the database.

For example, sample code:

```
<?php

$id  = $this->uri->segment(4);
$arr = explode(',', $id);
for ($kk = 0; $kk < count($arr); $kk++) {
    echo $id_val13 = $arr[$kk];
    $basicUrl                = $this->config->item("basicUrl");
    $basicUrl['bread_crumb'] = $this->breadcrumb();
    $query                   = $this->db->query("SELECT aa.id as id,customer_type_id,start_time,close_time,dd.name as customer_name,bb.name as vehicle_name,cc.name as driver_name,other_expensive,depature_city,destination_city,journey_status,payment,tour_file,DATE_FORMAT(aa.created_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as created_date FROM " . $this->tbl . " as aa
                                left join vehicle as bb on aa.vehicle_id=bb.id
                                left join driver as cc on aa.driver_id=cc.id
                                left join tbl_customer as dd on aa.customer_id=dd.id
                                WHERE aa.id = $id_val13");

    $result = array();

    if ($query->num_rows()) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $result_row   = array();
            $result_row[] = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk_id" id="chk_id" value="' . $row->id . '" />';
            $result_row[] = $row->id;
            $result_row[] = $row->customer_name;
            if ($row->customer_type_id == "1")
                $result_row[] = "Tour";
            else if ($row->customer_type_id == "2")
                $result_row[] = "Company";
            else if ($row->customer_type_id == "3")
                $result_row[] = "Guest";
            $result_row[] = $row->driver_name;
            $result_row[] = $row->vehicle_name;

            $result_row[] = $row->destination_city;
            $result_row[] = $row->start_time;
            $result_row[] = $row->close_time;
            $result_row[] = $row->payment;
            $result_row[] = $row->other_expensive;
            $result_row[] = $row->journey_status == "1" ? "Complete" : "On Progress";
            if ($row->tour_file != "") {
                $result_row[] = '<a href="' . base_url('uploads/' . $row->tour_file) . '">' . $row->tour_file . '</a>';
            } else {
                $result_row[] = "No File";
            }
            $result_row[] = $row->created_date;
            $action_btn   = action_button("Edit", $row->id) . action_button("Delete", $row->id) . action_button("Select", $row->id);
            $result_row[] = $action_btn;

            $result[] = $result_row;

            $i++;                                
        }                        
    }                
}


$tbl_header = array(
    "",
    "S NO",
    "Customer Name",
    "Type",
    "Driver Name",
    'Vehicle Name',
    "Destination City",
    "Start Time",
    "Close Time",
    "Rupee",
    "Other Expensive",
    "Journey Status",
    "Itinerary",
    "Created Date",
    array(
        "Edit",
        "Delete"
    )
);
$basicUrl['table'] = $this->makeTable($result, $tbl_header, $bool = TRUE);

$this->parser->parse("admin/center", $basicUrl);

?>
```

For example:

```
$array = array("1","2","6");
```

Normally using `explode()` and `for` loop, it display all the values. When I use select query using CodeIgniter, it displays the last row only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I have defined `$result` before for loop) Also this is not a good practice to use your code like this use controller and models to do all the logical and database work....

```
 <?php

    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $arr = explode(',', $id);
    $result=array();
    for ($kk = 0; $kk < count($arr); $kk++)
        {
          echo $id_val13 =  $arr[$kk];
            $basicUrl = $this->config->item("basicUrl");
            $basicUrl['bread_crumb'] = $this->breadcrumb();
            $query=$this->db->query("SELECT aa.id as id,customer_type_id,start_time,close_time,dd.name as customer_name,bb.name as vehicle_name,cc.name as driver_name,other_expensive,depature_city,destination_city,journey_status,payment,tour_file,DATE_FORMAT(aa.created_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as created_date FROM ".$this->tbl." as aa
                            left join vehicle as bb on aa.vehicle_id=bb.id
                            left join driver as cc on aa.driver_id=cc.id
                            left join tbl_customer as dd on aa.customer_id=dd.id
                            WHERE aa.id = $id_val13"); 


    if($query->num_rows()){
        $i=1;
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $result_row=array();
            $result_row[]='<input type="checkbox" name="chk_id" id="chk_id" value="'.$row->id.'" />';
            $result_row[]=$row->id;
            $result_row[]=$row->customer_name;
            if($row->customer_type_id=="1")
            $result_row[]="Tour";
            else if($row->customer_type_id=="2")
            $result_row[]="Company";
            else if($row->customer_type_id=="3")
            $result_row[]="Guest";
            $result_row[]=$row->driver_name;
            $result_row[]=$row->vehicle_name;

            $result_row[]=$row->destination_city;
            $result_row[]=$row->start_time;
            $result_row[]=$row->close_time;
            $result_row[]=$row->payment;
            $result_row[]=$row->other_expensive;
            $result_row[]=$row->journey_status=="1" ? "Complete" : "On Progress";
            if($row->tour_file!="")
            {
            $result_row[]='<a href="'.base_url('uploads/'.$row->tour_file).'">'.$row->tour_file.'</a>';
            }
            else
            {
            $result_row[]="No File";
            }
            $result_row[]=$row->created_date;
            $action_btn=action_button("Edit",$row->id).action_button("Delete",$row->id).action_button("Select",$row->id);
            $result_row[]=$action_btn;

            $result[]=$result_row;


            $i++;


    }


        }


         }


        $tbl_header=array("","S NO","Customer Name","Type","Driver Name",'Vehicle Name',"Destination City","Start Time","Close Time","Rupee","Other Expensive","Journey Status","Itinerary","Created Date",array("Edit","Delete"));
    $basicUrl['table']=$this->makeTable($result,$tbl_header,$bool=TRUE);

    $this->parser->parse("admin/center",$basicUrl);


     ?>
```